# Globe and Mail Cryptic April 11,2020

Tags: cryptic-clues

> Prison open, with a shift of four (4)

I believe the answer is STIR. Stir is a prison, but how does this fit the rest of the clue?

Comment: Is this a Fraser Simpson puzzle??

Answer (score 10):

> If you Caesar shift the word OPEN forward by 4 you get STIR.

Answer (score 0):

*Prison open, with a shift of four (4)*

> **STIR** ([def] Prison; "**OPEN**" with a shift of four, which is *rot4*)
>  To learn more about *rot4*, click [here](http://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=ROT13(true,true,4)&input=b3Blbg).

Comment: Sorry, The string "NaN" also causes CAPTCHA popup.

Comment: Good shout about the tag. I have removed it and edited your answer to remove the now redundant comment.

Comment: Sorry for the downvotes, I upvoted your answer.